# SASS Map - map-get no longer supporting interpolated values?

Tags: css, sass, interpolation

Previously in SCSS (version 3.4.21), I can use variable interpolation to get a specific item from a map:

```
$colors: (
  color-1: #aaa,
  color-2: #bbb,
  color-3: #ccc
);

@mixin color($shade) {
  color: map-get($colors, #{color-}$shade );
}

.element {
  @include color(2); 
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.element {
  color: #bbb;
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/7bd46098a6d29b657ce3740bdd9c3536)

In sass 4 (alpha), it doesn't work (or i'm screwing something up):

```
#{color-}$shade
```

It doesn't allow me to do that. Is there a reason this was taken out?

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is just a bit backwards.

```
@mixin color($shade) {
  color: map-get($colors, gray-#{$shade} );
}
```